# One unclear detail in Baum 1968 paper "On the cohomology of homogeneous spaces"

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, characteristic-classes

I was asking the same kind of question about a year ago, haven't got any distinct answer then, afterwards I got distracted, and now when I'm thinking about that question again - I still can't come up with any clue. Basically everything what I wanted to understand is on the screenshot:
[image]

We have two embeddings $U(n-1) \longrightarrow U(n)$ which give us different actions on cohomology of classifying spaces. But how did Baum come up with these expressions? I'm not even asking why they are different -  just how he calculated action of $\rho$ in each case? I have a slight understanding of the fact that $BU(n)$ is a base space of a universal bundle, and that $H^*(BU(n))$ is generated by  characteristic classes - can it help anyhow in deducing underlined expressions? I tried to think what cocycles in $BU(n)$ generate classes $x_{2i}, y_{2i}$ in $H^*$, but now I don't feel like it would help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to use properties of characteristic classes. In the first case, one can verify that the induced map $BU(n) \rightarrow BU(n+1)$ has the property that if $X \rightarrow BU(n+1)$ classifies a vector bundle, then the composition $X \rightarrow BU(n)$ classifies the direct sum with a trivial line bundle. The characteristic classes of the new bundle are the same as the old bundle according to the theory of Chern classes, so applying this to the identity $BU(n) \rightarrow BU(n)$ (which represents the universal vector bundle whose Chern classes are the $c_i$), we get the first formula.

In the second case, one can verify that the induced map $BU(n) \rightarrow BU(n+1)$ has the property that if $X \rightarrow BU(n)$ classifies a vector bundle, then the composition $X \rightarrow BU(n+1)$ classifies the direct sum with the tensor inverse of the determinant bundle. The determinant bundle has its single possible nontrivial class given by $c_1$ of the original bundle, so its inverse has its first class $-c_1$. Applying the Whitney sum formula, we get the second formula.

Comment: It’s still unclear to me how we make an assumption about which map classifies what bundle. Should we view $U(n-1)$ and $U(n)$ as structure groups to see that? It’s like we know something about the map $U(n-1) \longrightarrow U(n)$, the transition to some statement about $BU(n-1) \longrightarrow BU(n)$ is what bothers me.

Comment: @PeterBalabanov How important is the functoriality of $B$ to you? For example, it usually will be described as the realization of a large simplicial object. However, in the case of the unitary groups it can be described as moduli spaces of subspaces. So one could instead forget about the embeddings $U(n-1) \rightarrow U(n)$ and instead just start with the maps $BU(n-1) \rightarrow BU(n)$ which are given by the universal property that they pullback as I claim, and then view the theorems as about these maps.

Comment: If you really want to know that these are coming from the embeddings $U(n-1) \rightarrow U(n)$ you likely will have to get your hands dirty as you ask.

Comment: I'm familiar with construction of $B$ using $Gr_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty)$, but not much with moduli spaces in general. I'm not interested in starting from $U(n-1)$ embedding if it's hard, which I anticipated, but the author starts with them nevertheless. My question is then, how do one verifies that properties of $BU(n-1) \longrightarrow BU(n)$ really correspond to those matrice embeddings?

Comment: Intuitively it's "clear" that properties should be like that - giving sum with trivial bundle and inverse determinant, but how to check it more rigorously, I'm thinking about that.