# Classifying space functor: why do different maps $U(n-1) \longrightarrow U(n)$ give maps between $BU$'s that classify different bundles?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, vector-bundles, classifying-spaces

I already started discussion there:
[One unclear detail in Baum 1968 paper "On the cohomology of homogeneous spaces"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403849/one-unclear-detail-in-baum-1968-paper-on-the-cohomology-of-homogeneous-spaces). But I think that one is quite old, and this time the question is more specific, so let me ask again here.

There is a picture of two different inclusions of $U(n-1)$ into $U(n)$: one is aquired by just putting $1$ in the corner of a matrix, the second is by placing the inverse of determinant there instead. Then, if we consider the composition for arbitrary classifying map $X \longrightarrow BU(n-1) \longrightarrow BU(n)$, in the first case it would classify the new bundle which is the direct sum with a trivial bundle, in the second case - direct sum with the tensor inverse of the determinant bundle. This result is probably not surprising, but the question is - why so? What properties of $B$ as a functor should I consider to explain that?

In previous topic(link is above), Connor Malin suggested to start with maps $BU(n-1) \longrightarrow BU(n)$ which are given by the universal property that they pull bundles back the way I need. If I'm gonna go this way, how can I describe $BU$-maps in such a way, that they "fit" aforementioned inclusions of $U(n-1)$? In any case, I would be glad if you advise how to connect things that happen before and after applying $B$.

Instead of classifying any bundle by composition $X \longrightarrow BU(n-1) \longrightarrow BU(n)$, if talking about what's happening with cohomology I think it suffice to just say that unversal n-bundle pulls back to $EU(n-1)\oplus\varepsilon \longrightarrow BU(n-1)$ or $EU(n-1)\oplus \det(EU(n-1))^{-1} \longrightarrow BU(n-1)$.

Thank you! I kinda need this to give explanations in my course work, so if anyone can it to me I would appreciate that.

Comment: In general it should be true that if $f\colon X\to BU(n)$ classifies $E$, and $f'\colon X\to BU(k)$ classifies $E'$, then the composite $X\xrightarrow{f\times f'}BU(n)\times BU(k)\simeq B(U(n)\times U(k))\to BU(n+k)$ classifies $E\oplus E'$. In the first case the map $U(n-1)\to U(1)$ that has constant value $1$ induces the nullhomotopic map $0\colon BU(n-1)\to BU(1)$, so if $f\colon X\to BU(n-1)$ classifies $E$, then $X\xrightarrow{f} BU(n-1)\xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}\times 0} BU(n-1)\times BU(1)\to BU(n)$ classifies $E\oplus\epsilon$.

Comment: Also, if $\mathrm{det}\colon U(n)\to U(1)$ is the determinant map, then it should be true that if $f\colon X\to BU(n)$ classifies $E$, then the composite $X\xrightarrow{f} BU(n)\xrightarrow{B\mathrm{det}} BU(1)$ classifies the determinant line bundle of $E$.